# Find the position of a row in a given category along with total row in that category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in a SQL Server table:

```
Guid    Token   Category    DateCreated
-------------------------------------------
GUID1   TK1     Category1   1/9/2023 21:50
GUID2   TK2     Category1   1/10/2023 21:51
GUID3   TK3     Category1   1/11/2023 21:52
GUID4   TK4     Category1   1/12/2023 21:53
GUID5   TK5     Category1   1/13/2023 21:54
GUID6   TK6     Category1   1/14/2023 21:55
GUID7   TK7     Category1   1/15/2023 21:56
GUID8   TK8     Category1   1/16/2023 21:57
GUID9   TK9     Category1   1/17/2023 21:58
GUID10  TK10    Category1   1/18/2023 21:59
GUID11  TK11    Category1   1/19/2023 22:00
GUID12  TK12    Category2   1/20/2023 22:01
GUID13  TK13    Category2   1/21/2023 22:02
GUID14  TK14    Category2   1/22/2023 22:03
GUID15  TK15    Category2   1/23/2023 22:04
GUID16  TK16    Category3   1/24/2023 22:05
GUID17  TK17    Category3   1/25/2023 22:06
GUID18  TK18    Category3   1/26/2023 22:07
GUID19  TK19    Category3   1/27/2023 22:08
```

I wan to get the result as shown below (get the position of a token within its category and total tokens in that category):

```
Token   Position#   OutOftotal (Where Category ='Category1' and Token='TK8')
TK8         8           11

Token   Position#   OutOftotal (Where Category ='Category1' and Token='TK5')
TK5         5           11

Token   Position#   OutOftotal (Where Category ='Category3' and Token='TK17')
TK17        2           4
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: There are 11 rows of "Category 1" but only 1 of those has token = "TK8" - How can that be a OutOfTotal o=11? There are only 4 rows with "Category2" so how can that be OutOfTotal = 11? Please reconsider the expected result & how you have described your expected result.

Comment: Assuming a typo.   In your desired results  Category2 should be Category1 and Category3 should be Category2

Comment: Corrected the Question.
I was trying count() with the over clause, but messed with second count() for Total, was getting the position right from the first Count() but the total was coming incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using the window function `sum() over()`

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,[Position]   = sum(1) over (partition by Category order by [DateCreated])
      ,[OutofTotal] = sum(1) over (partition by Category)
 From  YourTable
 Where Category ='Category1' -- Optional but STRONGLY suggested
)
Select [Token]   
      ,[Position] 
      ,[OutofTotal]
 From cte 
 Where Category ='Category1' 
   and Token='TK8'
```

**Results**

```
Token   Position    OutofTotal
TK8     8           11
```

Comment: John, I have Question, the inner query(cte) would calculate the position & OutofTotal for all rows that qualify the where condition, hence you strongly suggesting filter by category.
My question is, is there a way to stop the numbering(position & OutofTotal) in CTE once it finds the Token, since i am only interested in that specific token number only?

Comment: @NSS  No, the entire sub-set of Category must be resolved.  That is why we have the STRONGLY suggested WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Guid        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Token       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,Category    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,DateCreated DATETIME  NOT NULL

);
INSERT INTO mytable
(Guid,Token,Category,DateCreated) VALUES 
('GUID1','TK1','Category1','1/9/2023 21:50'),
('GUID2','TK2','Category1','1/10/2023 21:51'),
('GUID3','TK3','Category1','1/11/2023 21:52'),
('GUID4','TK4','Category1','1/12/2023 21:53'),
('GUID5','TK5','Category1','1/13/2023 21:54'),
('GUID6','TK6','Category1','1/14/2023 21:55'),
('GUID7','TK7','Category1','1/15/2023 21:56'),
('GUID8','TK8','Category1','1/16/2023 21:57'),
('GUID9','TK9','Category1','1/17/2023 21:58'),
('GUID10','TK10','Category1','1/18/2023 21:59'),
('GUID11','TK11','Category1','1/19/2023 22:00'),
('GUID12','TK12','Category2','1/20/2023 22:01'),
('GUID13','TK13','Category2','1/21/2023 22:02'),
('GUID14','TK14','Category2','1/22/2023 22:03'),
('GUID15','TK15','Category2','1/23/2023 22:04'),
('GUID16','TK16','Category3','1/24/2023 22:05'),
('GUID17','TK17','Category3','1/25/2023 22:06'),
('GUID18','TK18','Category3','1/26/2023 22:07'),
('GUID19','TK19','Category3','1/27/2023 22:08');
```

use window functions such as `row_number` and `max with over`  and `Subquery` as follows

```
SELECT Token,
       Position,
       Max(Position)
         OVER(
           PARTITION by Category ) OutOftotal
FROM   (select Token,
               Category,
               DateCreated,
               row_number()
                 over (
                   PARTITION by Category
                   order by DateCreated ) Position
        FROM   mytable) M
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KvVvYIay)